# Should set::equal_range() return pair( set::lower_bound(), set::upper_bound() )

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std

Yeah, I know, I should have a repro, but the repro is annoying to produce. Before I produce one (and maybe give clang a bug) I want to ensure that my understanding of how things *should* work is correct.

- MSVC: Returns `set::equal_range()` as `{lower_bound(),upper_bound()}`.
- Clang: Returns `set::equal_range()` as `{lower_bound(),upper_bound()-1}`. (using stdlib=libc++) - and of course for my example.

My expectation for the last 20 years of STL programming is that MSVC is correct. And in fact the code I am editing I wrote 20 years ago and it used to work in both clang and gcc, but now is only working in MSVC (and maybe gcc - I haven't tried it - I am using some headers that are C++20 and only in stdlib=libc++ and MSVC but not in gcc ).

Anyway, is my assumption about what `set::equal_range()` should return correct?

Well, check it out:

Clang with -stdlib=libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/xfnasKa73

Clang without -stdlib=libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/5qYEj4MEd

Let me know if you think my comparator is bogus.

Here is the test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Range : public pair< size_t, size_t >
{
    using pair::pair;
    bool operator < ( Range const & _r ) const
    {
        return second < _r.first;
    }
};

typedef set< Range > vTySet;

int
main()
{
    vTySet setRanges = {{0,0},{9,9},{10,10},{13,13},{32,32},{34,34},{61,61},{65,90},{101,101},{110,110}};
    Range rngTest = { 97, 122 };
    pair< vTySet::iterator, vTySet::iterator > pritEqualRange = setRanges.equal_range( rngTest );
    size_t nDistEqualRange = distance( pritEqualRange.first, pritEqualRange.second );
    pair< vTySet::iterator, vTySet::iterator > pritLowerUpper = { setRanges.lower_bound( rngTest ), setRanges.upper_bound( rngTest ) };
    size_t nDistLowerUpper = distance( pritLowerUpper.first, pritLowerUpper.second );
    cout << "nDistEqualRange:" << nDistEqualRange << "\n";
    cout << "nDistLowerUpper:" << nDistLowerUpper << "\n";
}
```

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/equal_range : _"the first iterator may be obtained with lower_bound(), and the second with upper_bound()."_ Sooo, maybe a [mre] will help to clarify why you get these values.

Comment: I can't image that Clang and MS return different things for `set::equal_range()`. Most likely you have some UB in your code, and the difference you see if the consequence of that UB.

Comment: Wow, I mean I agree. I just wouldn't expect clang stdlib++ to have a bug... Alright, now I gotta work up a repro. I'll post it here before I give clang a bug. I was hoping there was something I might have been missing...

Comment: @Evg I would tend to agree with you. But I've spent hours looking at this. The comparator is checked on insertion for bogus comparison operators by both libraries.

Comment: If you have a custom comparator, check that it satisfies [strict weak ordering requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: It is just std::less<>. It such a simple example. Also, as I was saying, the libraries check for weak ordering requirements in the debug versions and I am see no such issues.

Comment: @DavidBien *the libraries check for weak ordering requirements in the debug versions* I believe that is a false assumption. How would it check that?

Comment: I'll edit the bug later and produce an example. I fixed my problem with my port back to Linux ( I ported to Windows 4 months ago to have an actually useful debugger ) by using upper_bound() and lower_bound() instead of equal range. The mere fact that the library should produce a difference is suspect to me. There should be two lookups to produce equal_range() - and those lookups should be for lower_bound() and upper_bound(). It would be inefficient (for example) to iterate from the lower_bound() to the upper_bound() because that might be the entire set.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. If clang is returning `upper_bound()-1` for the second iterator then your code has a bug or libc++ has a bug. It's not often you find a bug in a standard library implementation so you **really** need to make a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Blastfurnace well I agree, but I was just hoping someone would tell me why I was wrong about my long-lived assumption.

Comment: @super They do. I would have to search the MSVC STL to find the code, but I have encountered the issue where I didn't have a good comparator in the past.

Comment: @DavidBien The fact thtat it warns about this sometimes is not the same as a guarantee that it will always be able to detect it.

Comment: The standard is very clear about the return value of [`set::equal_range`](http://eel.is/c++draft/tab:container.assoc.req) (see bottom of table), what you're reporting is a bug. It would be fun if the problem was in libc++ but...

Comment: @Blastfurnace Excellent - and I also agree with you. Check out my examples, they work differently if stdlib=libc++ is used or not.

Comment: @Evg Let me know if you think my comparator is bogus. I think it is fine.

Comment: And someone give me a +1 since somehow I already got a -1. LOL!!!!

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'd be happy to give clang a bug but I wanted to make sure I didn't have a bogus comparator, and indeed it may be one. I'd like folks here to check my example - it is incredibly simple.

Comment: Your comparator doesn't satisfy strict weak ordering.

Comment: @Evg why? I'm trying to figure out by reading about strict weak ordering but I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any custom comparator that is used for `std::set` should satisfy [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements (strict weak ordering + equivalence). You have UB in your code, and the difference you see is the consequence of that UB. In your example, the elements are pairs `(a, b)` and the comparator (let's call it `less`) is `(a, b) < (c, d)` iff `b < c`.

Consider two pairs `(5, 2)` and `(6, 3)`. The asymmetry property requires that if `(5, 2) < (6, 3)` is true, then `(6, 3) < (5, 2)` should be false. But it is also true:

```
Range r1(5, 2);
Range r2(6, 3);
std::cout << less(r1, r2); // 1
std::cout << less(r2, r1); // 1, but should be 0
```

The transitivity of the equivalence relation is also broken by such a comparator:

```
Range r1(1, 3);
Range r2(2, 5);
Range r3(4, 6);
std::cout << equiv(r1, r2); // 1
std::cout << equiv(r2, r3); // 1
std::cout << equiv(r1, r3); // 0, but should be 1
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qccYosTje)

It should be noted that these requirements apply not only to the elements in the set, but also to those that you pass as a key to `std::set::equal_range(const Key&)`.

Comment: Yes, but *if* I guarantee that all pairs are disjoint then it will be a good comparator - i.e. it is a good comparator for a disjoint set. And then I can use (lower_bound(), upper_bound()) with a search parameter that is non-disjoint with respect to members of the set - i.e. just like I am doing. It's only equal_range() that will return a bogus result in that case - and also due to implementation details - i.e. it works in everything but stdlib++.

Comment: When I insert into the set I only insert disjoint pairs - i.e. pairs that don't intersect with any other pairs currently present in the set. I want to (and kinda need to) be able to search with a Range that is non-disjoint with respect to the current members of the set. My other solution (of course) is to form two Range objects from the endpoints of my search range and search the set with the lower endpoint as input to lower_bound and the upper endpoint as input to upper bound.

Comment: @DavidBien *if ... all pairs are disjoint*. But in your example `(97, 122)` is not disjoint with all other ranges. Those requirements apply not only to the elements in the range, but also to those that you pass as a key to `equal_range()`.

Comment: Well exactly - I am updating the alphabet set in this case. I have a new input range. I need to merge that into the exist set of disjoint ranges. So, what I will do instead, which is well defined, is to search with lower_bound(97,97) and upper_bound(122,122). Then I have range of elements into which I am merging the new alphabet range.

Comment: I wrote this code in 1999... lol. It has worked on gcc, intel, msvc, old clang, you name it and I switch to stdlibc++ and there ya go...

Comment: One thing that is interesting to me is that equal_range() doesn't just produce (lower_bound(),upper_bound()) because that was my assumption, and clearly since the answer is different for my example, at least for stdlibc++ it is not the case.

Comment: @DavidBien If you violate the preconditions, then it can produce anything. One idea behind having `equal_range()` is that it can be more efficient than two independent calls of `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()`. No surprise that two different algorithms produce different results in general.

Comment: Yeah of course I get that. Found another issue related to equal_range() grepping my old code - which I barely understand having left it idle for 20 years while coding at a dotcom. In this case I hacked it using a multimap<> to get around the fact that I was storing overlapping Ranges as keys in it. It worked amazingly well, but the correct way is so much simpler - and is guaranteed to work. So this has been quite a fruitful exercise. Clearly I understood that I needed a multimap because I was storing "equivalent" keys but the comparator I was using wasn't valid so it could cause issues.