# How do I fix an Invalid Comparator error?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

MSVS 16.9.3

Win7-64

I get an invalid comparator error on the second execution of my sort comparator passed to the C++ Sort function provided in `<algorithm>`. I don't understand why I am getting this error! The sort routine call is:

```
sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), remsort);
```

`sorted` is defined like this:

```
vector<ADI::RDA_Asset*>& sorted = *(new vector<ADI::RDA_Asset*>);
```

These are the three versions of `remsort` that I used:

Version 1: always works:

```
bool HOAReports::remsort(ADI::RDA_Asset* lhs, ADI::RDA_Asset* rhs) { 
   return (lhs->getRem() < rhs->getRem());
};
```

Version 2: works on the first call to remsort by the sort routine, fails on the second:

```
bool HOAReports::remsort(ADI::RDA_Asset* lhs, ADI::RDA_Asset* rhs) { 
   return (  (lhs->getRem() < rhs->getRem())
          || ((lhs->getCatName()).compare(rhs->getCatName()) < 0)
          || ((lhs->getRDAName()).compare(rhs->getRDAName()) < 0)
          };
```

Version 3: works on the first call to remsort by the sort routine, fails on the second:

```
bool HOAReports::remsort(ADI::RDA_Asset* lhs, ADI::RDA_Asset* rhs) {
   bool return_value = (  (lhs->getRem() < rhs->getRem())
                      || ((lhs->getCatName()).compare(rhs->getCatName()) < 0)
                      || ((lhs->getRDAName()).compare(rhs->getRDAName()) < 0)
                       ); 
   return return_value;
};
```

Version 2/3 have the same functionality. On the first and second call to `remsort` only (`(lhs->getRem() < rhs->getRem()`) is executed and the return_value is true. Looking at the failed assertion, it looks like the assertion is checked on both calls but fails on the second.

The MSVS code which fails is:

```
// FUNCTION TEMPLATE _Debug_lt_pred
template <class _Pr, class _Ty1, class _Ty2,
    enable_if_t<is_same_v<_Remove_cvref_t<_Ty1>, _Remove_cvref_t<_Ty2>>, int> = 0>
constexpr bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr&& _Pred, _Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right) noexcept(
    noexcept(_Pred(_Left, _Right)) && noexcept(_Pred(_Right, _Left))) {
    // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering, when the arguments are the cv-same-type
    const auto _Result = static_cast<bool>(_Pred(_Left, _Right));
    if (_Result) {
        _STL_VERIFY(!_Pred(_Right, _Left), "invalid comparator");
    }

    return _Result;
}
```

Comment: A comparator is not an arbitrary function. It should satisfy some [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

Comment: You might take a look at `std::tie` it makes writing correct comparisons easy. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

Comment: If you have a struct with two members x and y, you need `a.x < b.x || (a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y)`. You in essence have just `a.x < b.x || a.y < b.y`. This latter version is easy to write, easy to remember, and wrong.

Comment: @Evg I don't fully understand the argument. In Version 3: the evaluation of return_value should not be seen by the runtime (?) to generate an error. But even so, the failure occurred only on the second invocation and not the first, and both invocations only executed the first clause. But I did change all referenced functions to const function, which I had hoped would be a satisfactory answer. It was not. The second invocation still failed.

Comment: Try something like this: https://pastebin.com/S3BErjGe

Comment: @TedLyngmo `vector<ADI::RDA_Asset*>& sorted = *(new vector<ADI::RDA_Asset*>);. Don't let the name fool you. In order to isolate the sorted data from the original data, the original data was copied into `sorted and this vector was sorted. 1remsort is a static member function. As a static function it works just fine.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I looked at std::ties and don't see how that helps. Can you explain what I should do?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.But why is it wrong? This is a runtime error and the runtime seems to be telling me something. Only I can't figure out what?

Comment: It is wrong because such a comparator violates [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirements.

Comment: @Evg Although I didn't do exactly what you coded, I followed your intent. Separating the conditional clauses into separate `if` statements worked. I don't know why. I don't know where. And I don't know how. But it worked and now I'm a happy but puzzled camper.

Comment: The canonical recipe is this: compare the first pair of subelements, if they are different, return the result of their comparison, if they are equal (equivalent), repeat the same algorithm for the second pair and so on.

Comment: @Evg I looked at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare requirements, and then, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BinaryPredicate. I changed all functions called to `const function` which I think satisfied `bin_pred` requirements. Under Version 2: it failed after the change. However, I did redo the code as suggested, but damn it all, I'm still befuddled. Oh well, we call "success" success, so I guess I should be a happy camper. Sigh. Thanks to all.

Comment: Earlier today I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67043039) with an explicit demonstration why some comparator fails to satisfy the Compare requirements. You can do a similar thing for yours one.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez The example of `operator<` on the page is exactly what want to do and it satisfies the strict weak ordering requirement. `return std::tie(lhs->getRem(), lhs->getCatName(), lhs->getRDAName()) < std::tie(rhs->getRem(), rhs->getCatName(), rhs->getRDAName());`

Comment: Why on earth are you defining `sorted` in such a way instead of making a normal automatic variable,`vector<ADI::RDA_Asset*> sorted;` ? You now need to manually `delete &sorted;` for no reason at all.

Comment: What your code says is that for two instances `x` and `y`, `&x` should compare less than `&y` if any of the three member values in `x` is less than the corresponding member value in `y`. The problem is that if `&x < &y`, then it **must not** also be true that `&y < &x`. Now, consider what happens if one of the member values in `x` is less than the corresponding value in `y`, but another of the member values in `x` is greater. Will it be true that `&x < &y`? Yes; do you understand why? Will it be true that `&y < &x`? Yes; do you understand why? This is a problem; do you understand why?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry about the delay. MSVS has been giving me fits.When I attempt to construct objects on the runtime stack, all sorts of nasties occur. So being wise I find something that works and repeat that something ad-infinitum.But I did try what you suggested and, of course, MSVS gave me "requires and initializer". ...sorted(); also doesn't work. I think it's poor compiler writing. Whenever I try to put something on the runtime stack, MSVS seem to become quite annoyed. That's why you see that ugly piece of code. Netbeans, my preferred IDE, can't get staff. Eclipse had errors. So MSVS s it.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez It's hard to say what it is that is giving you problems. Perhaps it's the raw pointers that you use? I added a demo to my answer that should work in MSVC too.

Comment: No, it is never the compiler. It is always the programmer. (For values of "always" that are sufficient for this discussion). I recommend asking a separate question about that ugly piece of code.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.I've been in this business a long, long time, and during that time I've discovered more than one compiler error. Microsoft seems to be proud of theirs. It is never true that 'always' is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison function does not fulfill the *strict weak* ordering requirements. See [C++ named requirements: *Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare).

In your specific case, you could implement it like this:

```
bool HOAReports::remsort(ADI::RDA_Asset* lhs, ADI::RDA_Asset* rhs) {
    if(lhs->getRem() < rhs->getRem()) return true;
    if(rhs->getRem() < lhs->getRem()) return false;

    // if we get here, lhs.getRem() == rhs.getRem()

    auto cmp = lhs->getCatName().compare(rhs->getCatName());
    if(cmp) return cmp < 0;

    // if we get here, lhs->getCatName() == rhs->getCatName()

    return lhs->getRDAName() < rhs->getRDAName();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3a57e881n)

Or simpler, use [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <tuple>

bool HOAReports::remsort(ADI::RDA_Asset* lhs, ADI::RDA_Asset* rhs) {
    return
        std::tuple{lhs->getRem(), lhs->getCatName(), lhs->getRDAName()}
        <
        std::tuple{rhs->getRem(), rhs->getCatName(), rhs->getRDAName()};
}
```

Comment: Looked at the demo. I ended up using a similar piece of code. But, I like your "tuple" answer. When time is available I intend to 'get smart' and study how to use it.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Ok, great!

Comment: @Ted_Lyngmo I looked at your "What should .." and followed the procedure. I will try to do this to my other questions as well although I think some of them have been decayed to obscurity. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ArthurSchwarez Great! Re: "_I think some of them have been decayed to obscurity_" - It's never to late to accept and upvote a good answer. The person who wrote the answer will appreciate it - even if it happens a long time after.